# pushing character in a direction consistently in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have a particle effect that shoots bubbles, and when the character enters the stream of bubbles I'd like to create the effect that the bubbles consistently move the character in the direction they're going. How would I go about doing that? I put a collider in the particle effects already and have tried this code so far.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GeyserPush : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Player;
    public float Speed;



    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject == Player)
        {
            //other.transform.Translate((Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime), Space.World);
            Player.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
            print("Pushing");
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == Player)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The code is incomplete since I do not have a full solution yet. The character does have a rigidbody equipped to it too.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Unity but my understanding is that `OnTriggerEnter` only runs once, when the objects collide. You want to put that code in the game loop (the `Update` function) inside a check to see if the player and collider are overlapping/touching.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll have to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the table at the bottom of [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html), if both the particles and the player have `Rigidbody`, it might be better to use `OnCollisionEnter()` instead.

You could add a force on the player's `Rigidbody` per collision in the direction that your particles are moving like so:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject == Player)
    {
        //other.transform.Translate((Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime), Space.World);
        Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(targetDirection * Speed);
        print("Pushing");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be willing to try it, but what/how would I call particleDirection as?

Comment: @shinjabo I have edited my answer. From the code you have provided, I'm assuming you just want the particles to push the player upwards, so `targetDirection` can be the `Vector3.up` you used before

Comment: This works but the weird thing is that the box collider won't make the script work when "is Trigger" is checked, but when I uncheck it and place my character inside the particle effect to test it does work. Of course, I can't get the character out of the particle effect due to being boxed in by the box collider. Any suggestions?

Comment: @shinjabo Firstly, I don't think its a good idea to check `isTrigger` since that is usually used for trigger volumes and not actual collisions like the one you are trying to implement. Secondly, correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like you have given the entire of the particle system a `Collider` when instead, it should be on the particles themselves

Comment: @shinjabo The `ParticleSystem` component comes with a `Collision` module which can suit your needs. There, you can specify what the particles collide with as well as the collision response